# Symfony ajax objects are null after json_decode

Tags: json, ajax, symfony, controller, decode

I have an ajax function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#{{ form.vars.name }}_documentlist').change(function() {
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      data: $("form").serialize(),
    });
  });
});
</script>
```

documentlist is a multiselect dropdowns and the selected "entries" are sent to my ActivationController:

```
/**
  * @Route("/document/bulkdeactivate", name="documentBundle_document_bulkDeactivate")
  * @Template()
  */
  public function bulkDeactivateAction(Request $request) {
      $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
      $selected_documents[] = $request->getContent();
      dump($selected_documents);
      foreach($selected_documents as $document){
      $params = json_decode($document, true);
      dump($params);
      }
      $form = $this->createForm(DocumentDeactivationType::class);
      $form->handleRequest($request);

      if ($form->isSubmitted()) {
        foreach($params as $document) {
  $document->setActive(false);
            $em->persist($document);
            $em->flush();
            $this->addFlash(
            'success',
            'The document has been deactivated!'
            );
            return $this->redirectToRoute('documentBundle_document_list');
            }
          }
          return $this->render('DocumentBundle:Panels:ActivationPanel.html.twig', array(
            'form' => $form->createView(),
          ));
}
```

But in my controller I'm doing something wrong. I'd like to persist the selected entries to my database and therefor **decode** them to objects.
Here are my thoughts to my code:
$selected_documents is an array because I can select several documents from my dropdown. I have the foreach loop for the decode because I can't decode an array and I didn't figure out how it would work better.
The first dump($selected_Documents) returns e.g.

```
array:1 [▼
  0 => "search=&document_deactivation%5Bdocumentlist%5D%5B%5D=41"
]
```

the second dump($params) then returns **null** so apparently something with my decoding action is going wrong. I've read the documentation but can't really figure out what my mistake is.

Do you need any further information? would be happy about help!

Comment: try to show POSTed data by looking at $request->request->all()

Comment: @MameMedouneDiop what do you mean? you want to see the data or I should use it instead of **getContent**?
and how would i proceed with it?

Comment: @MameMedouneDiop
**edit**
I replaced my getContent() with your solution and it's acutally working fine, thanks for that! 
Now my only problem is, that I have strings decoded but I need objects. Do you know how I could achieve this?

Comment: what dit you get when you use $request->request->all()?

Comment: array:2 [▼
  "search" => ""
  "document_deactivation" => array:1 [▼
    "documentlist" => array:1 [▼
      0 => "42"
    ]
  ]
]

that was the output when I dumped the data, @MameMedouneDiop

Comment: Are the number in the documentlist array the ids of your documents?

Comment: @MameMedouneDiop yes exactly! **42** is the document ID!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155781/discussion-between-mame-medoune-diop-and-sonja).